# Is it possible to have an Azure DevOps Pipeline publish artifacts to a secondary GIT repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

We are currently trying to automate builds of our legacy VB6 application in Azure DevOps.  One of the (many) idiosyncrasies of VB6 is that you need to put line numbers in your code in order for your exception messages to tell you on which line of code the exception occurred (welcome to 1998, it is the future).  We have a tool that gets run as part of the build process that generates an intermediate set of source code with the line numbers which then gets built into binaries.  Keeping the line numbered code around is important for debugging purposes, what we would like to do is commit the line numbered code to a secondary GIT repository and then tag the commit with the build number.  How do I go about publishing my build artifacts to a git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I go about publishing my build artifacts to a git repository?

You can add a [CMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)/[PS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) task at the end of your pipeline to run git-related commands to clone the repo locally, do changes and commit,tag commit and then push the changes to remote repo.

1.If the second git repo is a github repo, you can try script below in CMD task:

```
git clone https://{userName}:{userPassword}@github.com/xxx/{RepoName}.git

git checkout master

git config --global user.email MyEmail@outlook.com

git config --global user.name MyName

copy "Test.txt" {RepoName}

cd {RepoName}

git add .

git commit -m "Add line numbered code."

git tag $(Build.BuildNumber)

git push https://{userName}:{userPassword}@github.com/xxx/{RepoName}.git master tag $(Build.BuildNumber)
```

You should replace the `{userName},{userPassword} and {RepoName}` with your own info. For step5, you can use either `copy` or `xcopy` command to copy the file(including .zip file)/files to the folder whose name is `{RepoName}` (Your second repo will be downloaded into this folder).

2.If the second repo is an Azure Devops git Repo, you also need to make sure your current `ProjectName Build Service` has the permission to create tag (Project Settings=>Repositories=>Permissions):

[image]

And to do clone/push with Azure Repo, [PAT](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2455#issuecomment-439503194) with limited permission is more recommended.